# Spherical coordinates what are the coordinates of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I am getting a bit confused about the language for coordinate systems. I have chosen spherical coordinates as an example, but my confusion is general. Let's say we have a vector 
$$\vec A=A_r e_r+A_\theta e_\theta +A_\phi e_\phi$$
Now from linear algebra I would say that the coordinates of this vector with respect to the given basis is $(A_r, A_\theta, A_\phi)$. Wikipedia among other places, however, says that the coordinates of this system are $(r,\theta,\phi)$. So how do we define the coordinates in a vector space given that these two ideas seem to be different? And wouldn't a better term for $(r,\theta,\phi)$ be the parameters of the coordinate system rather then the coordinates?

Comment: Warning! In non-linear coordinate systems, you must carefully distinguish points and vectors.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro please can you expand

Comment: A point in $\R^3$ is identified by the three coordinates $r, \theta,\phi$. (Except for singular points of the coordinate system such as the origin, which have to be treated separately.) At any point, there is a set of vectors $e_r, e_\theta, e_\phi$, which depends on the base point. You express all vectors that are applied at the base point in terms of them. Your vector $A$ is therefore applied at that particular point and not a free vector of $\R^3$. In Cartesian coordinate system one can happily ignore such details because one identifies a point with its position vector.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for responding. Is the following basically what you are saying: We have two different concepts of coordinates here, the first $A_r, A_\phi, A_\theta$ denotes the coordinates of a vector in a vector space whilst the coordinates $r,\theta,\phi$ denote the coordinates in an affine space. So one is the coordinates for the vector space and the other the ‘coordinates’ for the affine space?

Comment: Yes, you can think at it that way. Only problem is that $r, \theta, \phi$ are not really "affine" coordinates, because they are curvilinear. The right mathematical standpoint for this concept is that of differential geometry, which treat the "point set" $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a differentiable manifold. For each point $p\in \mathbb{R}^3$, the "vector set" $\mathbb{R}^3_p$ is the tangent space at $p$. In the end, there is no change in actual computation, only a different conceptual point of view.